# Having trouble with identity users in my asp.net 2.2 web app, receiving 'invalid object name Aspnetusers' error

Tags: c#, html, sql-server, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am learning how to use `SigninManager`, `UserManager`, etc for my web app, but I am getting this error:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'

I was following a demo and trying to modify it to fit my database user requirements. I have a users table in my SQL Server called "VisUser" which additional required information such as lastname, username, email, etc.

Before trying to implement identities I had a model for users then used the same code and inserted it into my applicationuser. From what I've seen online is that after you implement the database context with IdentityUser a series of tables are generated into your database in SQL Server however that never occurs for me.

My 'Accounts' model

```
public class Accounts
{
    [Table("VisUser")]
    public class VisUser
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(0), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "FirstName")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(0), MaxLength(2), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Middle Initial")]
        public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(1), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(4), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Username")]
        public string VisUserName { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress, MaxLength(256), Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string VisEmail { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(6), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Password), Display(Name = "UserPassword")]
        public string UserPassword { get; set; }

        [BindProperty]
        [Required]
        [MinLength(6), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Password), Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        [Compare("UserPassword", ErrorMessage = "The Password does not match the Confirmed Password")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

ApplicationUser:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(0), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "FirstName")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(0), MaxLength(2), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Middle Initial")]
    public string MiddleInitial { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(1), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(4), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Text), Display(Name = "Username")]
    public string VisUserName { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress, MaxLength(256), Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string VisEmail { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(6), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Password), Display(Name = "UserPassword")]
    public string UserPassword { get; set; }

    [BindProperty]
    [Required]
    [MinLength(6), MaxLength(50), DataType(DataType.Password), Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
    [Compare("UserPassword", ErrorMessage = "The Password does not match the Confirmed Password")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Databasecontext:

```
public class DatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {

    }
    public DbSet<CategoryTB> CategoryTB { get; set; }           
    public DbSet<VisUser> VisUser { get; set; }           
}
```

What I added into my startup.cs:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
         // adds UserStore and RoleStore for Usermanager and RoleManager
         .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>()
         // adds a provider that generates unique keys and hashes for things like forgot password links, phone verification etc
         .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Register page html:

```
<body>
    <form asp-route-returnUrl="@Model.ReturnUrl" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="VisUser.FirstName"></label>
                <input asp-for="VisUser.FirstName" class="form-control" />
                <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="VisUser.FirstName"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="VisUser.MiddleInitial"></label>
                <input asp-for="VisUser.MiddleInitial" class="form-control" />
                <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="VisUser.MiddleInitial"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="VisUser.LastName"></label>
                <input asp-for="VisUser.LastName" class="form-control" />
                <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="VisUser.LastName"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="VisUser.VisEmail"></label>
                <input asp-for="VisUser.VisEmail" class="form-control" />
                <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="VisUser.VisEmail"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="VisUser.VisUserName"></label>
                <input asp-for="VisUser.VisUserName" cl class="form-control" />
                <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="VisUser.VisUserName"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="VisUser.UserPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="VisUser.UserPassword" cl class="form-control" />
                <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="VisUser.UserPassword"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <label asp-for="VisUser.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="VisUser.ConfirmPassword" cl class="form-control" />
                <span class="alert-danger" asp-validation-for="VisUser.ConfirmPassword"></span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="/allcustomer">Cancel</a>
    </form>
</body>
```

Code behind Register html:

```
public class RegisterModel : PageModel
{
    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }
    private DatabaseContext _context;

    [BindProperty]
    public VisUser VisUser { get; set; }

    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public RegisterModel(DatabaseContext _context, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        DatabaseContext _context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager; 
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser
            {
                FirstName = VisUser.FirstName,
                MiddleInitial = VisUser.MiddleInitial,
                LastName = VisUser.LastName,
                Email = VisUser.VisEmail,
                UserName = VisUser.VisUserName,
                UserPassword = VisUser.UserPassword
            };

            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, user.UserPassword);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(returnUrl))
                {
                    return LocalRedirect("~/");
                }
                else
                {
                    return Redirect(returnUrl);
                }
            }
        }
        return Page();        //if reaches here then something's wrong (redirects to current page)
    }
}
```

I believe this is all the relevant pieces of code for implementing identityusers.

What I would like to achieve is for the user to be added then have the relevant information stored inside my `VisUser` table in my SQL Server, then sign the user in so that I have access to who is logged in and can change the navbar appropriately. However, what occurs is that the application returns:

> SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers'

when I try to pass the user and password into the `UserManager` in:

```
var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, user.UserPassword);
```

Comment: You don't show any configuration data. I'm assuming that the Connection String for the database context doesn't include a `Catalog` keyword and the user's default database is somewhere other than your ASP.NET user database.

Comment: Isn't the catalog only used for when you are using multiple databases? In this case I am only trying to use 1 database in my ms sql server.  However, my connection string looks like this:   Data Source=DANNY\\SQLEXPRESS; UID=sa; Password=-----------; Database=VispitesTest;                                                       Please let me know if there is anymore configuration information and thank you in advance.

Comment: In SQL Server > Security > Logins each SQL Login and Windows Login has a default database property. e.g.: `sa` goes to `master`. When you don't specify a database in your connection string that default database is where the connection winds up. The property has different names for different drivers, too. For [System.Data.SqlClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder) that property is "Initial Catalog",

Comment: Oh but I thought the 'Database=VispitesTest' was able to specify the correct database.  I was originally able to perform correct CRUD operations on that database on the correct tables.  However, I tried modifying my connectionstring to 'Initial catalog=VispitesTest' by replacing that the previous 'Database=VispitesTest' however the same SqlException: Invalid object name 'AspNetUsers' occurs. Also, I noticed that my RegisterModel constructor with the dbcontext, signingmanager, and usermanager says that it is not being referenced at all.  Maybe there's an isssue with how I implement usermanager?

Comment: After changing the database, have you run add-migration and update-database to sycn the database and model?